# Authentication Youtube API Java

Tags: java, jsp, oauth, youtube-data-api

I couldn't get a clue how to authenticate YouTube in Java. The samples shared by YouTube aren't that helpful and are aiming for Android authentication. I would helpful for any hints. Thanks in regard.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java ?

Comment: I don't want to store the json containing my account data file locally...